# ASP.NET Core Publishing appsettings.json File From Wrong Project

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have a solution with 2 projects. One is an ASP.NET Core 5 Web Application, and it runs fine if I F5 run it in IIS Express. The other project is a .NET Core 5 Console application, which also runs fine if I F5 run it.

However, when I try to Publish the Web Application, the published folder contains the appsettings.*.json files from the Console Application instead of the Web Application.

Does anybody have any advice on how to get the Web Application's appsettings.*.json files published with it?

Comment: Shouldn't your first consideration be why appsettings.json files from the Console Application instead of the Web Application?

Comment: Samwu that's exactly my question.

Comment: Can you show me your Project structure? and how did you create these two projects in VS?